# How can my Provider access the previous version of pacts rather than the latest one?

Tags: pact

My consumer publishes pacts with version 1.0, 1.1, 1.2. By default my Provider is accessing the last published pact with version 1.2. How can my Provider access the previous version of pacts, 1.1 or 1.2?

Comment: Aruna please also ensure that you accept answers if they are helping you. Giving feedback is an important part of the Stack Overflow ecosystem that both motivates those helping you, as well as signal to future visitors the usefulness of answers.

Answer (score 1):

[Tagging](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/wiki/Using-tags) is the main way to control which pacts are retrieved when verifying a provider.

What is the reason for needing to verify each version separately - can multiple versions of a consumer co-exist simultaneously in production (e.g. multiple versions of a mobile app).

You might also want to read this guide:  https://docs.pact.io/best_practices/pact_nirvana